# Protocol not firing

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitapgesturerecognizer

My protocol is not firing at all, and I am conforming it to the method that I want it to trigger. Any help would be well appreciated!

```
public class NoteCardView:UIView {
@IBInspectable var delegate: NoteCardViewDelegate?

 func handleTitleLabelTap(_ recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Verified this function is being called and has the right value!
self.delegate?.noteCardViewTitleLabelDidRecieveTap(MainViewController.NoteCardArray[Int(recognizer.view!.tag)])
 }
}

public protocol NoteCardViewDelegate {
// This should be being fired..
func noteCardViewTitleLabelDidRecieveTap(_ view: NoteCardView!)
}

extension MainViewController: NoteCardViewDelegate {
// this is what the handleTitleLabelTap function should do!
func noteCardViewTitleLabelDidRecieveTap(_ view: NoteCardView!) {
    print("6")
    let card:NoteCardView = (view)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {

        card.contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: (self.elementPlacement / 4) + 20)

        card.contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 100)

    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in

        self.elementPlacement = (self.elementPlacement + 1)
        card.titleLabelTapGestureRecognizer!.isEnabled = !(self.elementPlacement == 5)
    })
}
}
```

Comment: Why did you delete your previous question? Where's the code to setup the tap gesture?

Comment: @rmaddy I realized my previous question was poorly worded and had extraneous code. The code for my tap gesture definitely works after testing it, I put print statements and figured out it was triggering the method handleTitleLabelTap. handleTitleLabelTap is not triggering the protocol now, and hence this question. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Clearly `self.delegate` is `nil`. Figure out why after confirming that is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

`self.delegate?.noteCardViewTitleLabelDidRecieveTap(MainViewController.NoteCardArray[Int(recognizer.view!.tag)])`

...won't do anything if self.delegate is nil. The "?" tells the compiler to check for nil and stop if **is** nil.

I suggest adding a print statement:

`print("About to call delegate. delegate = \(delegate)")
delegate?.noteCardViewTitleLabelDidRecieveTap(MainViewController.NoteCardArray[Int(recognizer.view!.tag)])`

BTW, self is unneeded and you should omit it. The only time you usually need to specify self is in a closure, where the compiler insists that you include it in order to "make the capture semantics explicit." My advice is to leave it out unless the compiler complains.

Also note that it doesn't really make sense to say "my protocol isn't firing." A protocol is an agreed-upon set of methods/properties. It's like a lingo used to communicate between objects that understand the protocol. It would be better to say "my delegate method isn't getting invoked."

Comment: I gather since you accepted my answer and deleted your comment asking how to set the delegate that you figured it out?